# Distribute subcommands over head command to avoid writing same words twice?

Tags: zsh, command-substitution, read

I would like to try to write this command:

```
while read -r repo; do gh repo delete $repo; done <<< $(gh repo list --no-archived)
```

which basically cleans up my GitHub and deletes everything that I did not archive because I wanted to keep it on hand as a backup.

I would like there to be some way - without using aliases - to not have to write "gh repo" twice - elegantly. Some way of passing the two subcommands "list" and "delete" into that "head", something like:

```
gh repo $(list | while read -r repo; do delete $repo; done)
```

Would there be any possible way to do that? This is Zsh, but if any other shell has that capability, I'd love to know.

Comment: I have not used github cli, but have you tried doing `gh repo list --no-archived | xargs -n1 gh repo delete`? This assumes that the output of the first command prints out only the repo names and that repo names can only be deleted one at a time.

Comment: Other than re-writing the `gh` app there is no way to do the two operations in a single invocation...